# JavaFX: Trying to display text in labels, in new Window, after button press

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm attempting to make a windowed program using JavaFx and SceneBuilder. For some reason I'm unable to get the text I wish to appear on the final window after a button press. The window opens but the text is never displayed or applied to my Labels.  I'm getting a Nullpointer exception on my displayTime method,I dont understand why. Heres the code for my controller class as well as the FXML file for my final window.

```
package plan;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainController{

    @FXML
    public String act1, act2, act3, act4;

    @FXML
    public Button input;

    @FXML
    public Button proceed;

    @FXML
    public Button start;

    @FXML
    public Button calcTime;

    @FXML
    public TextField task1;
    @FXML
    public TextField task2;
    @FXML
    public TextField task3;
    @FXML
    public TextField task4;
    @FXML
    public TextField hours;

    @FXML
    public Label fplan1;
    @FXML
    public Label fplan2;
    @FXML
    public Label fplan3;
    @FXML
    public Label fplan4;
    @FXML
    public Label timesCalc;


    @FXML
    private void startPlan(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NewPlan.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); //creation of a scene
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("YOUR DAILY PLAN");
        primaryStage.show();// Displays window/ stage 
        Stage currentStage =  (Stage)start.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();

    }

    @FXML
    private void inputDay(ActionEvent event)throws IOException {

        Stage currentStage =  (Stage)input.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("NormalDay.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); //creation of a scene
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("YOUR DAILY PLAN");
        primaryStage.show();// Displays window/ stage

    }

    @FXML
    private void calcTime(ActionEvent event)throws IOException {


        Day day = new Day(Integer.parseInt(hours.getText()));

        act1 = "Time you have for " + task1.getText() + " is " + Integer.toString(day.getT(1)) + " hours " + Integer.toString(day.getT(11));
        act2 = "Time you have for " + task2.getText() + " is " + Integer.toString(day.getT(2)) + " hours " + Integer.toString(day.getT(22));
        act3 = "Time you have for " + task3.getText() + " is " + Integer.toString(day.getT(3)) + " hours " + Integer.toString(day.getT(33));
        act4 = "Time you have for " + task4.getText() + " is " + Integer.toString(day.getT(4)) + " hours " + Integer.toString(day.getT(44));

        timesCalc.setText("Time Calculation Completed!");

        //TIMES CALCULATED MESSAGE
    }

    @FXML
    private void displayTime(ActionEvent event)throws IOException {

        Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FinalDay.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root); //creation of a scene
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("YOUR DAILY PLAN");
        primaryStage.show();// Displays window/ stage

        fplan1.setText("TEST");
        fplan2.setText(act2);
        fplan3.setText(act3);
        fplan4.setText(act3);

        //ANOTHER display method??? times still wont show on final page after continue button



    }



}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="plan.MainController">
   <children>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="704.0">
         <children>
            <Label text="YOUR PLAN" textFill="#3751e8">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Italic" size="36.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <VBox layoutX="11.0" layoutY="121.0" prefHeight="378.0" prefWidth="683.0" spacing="50.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="fplan1" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="762.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="fplan2" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="700.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="fplan3" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="957.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="fplan4" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="734.0">
               <font>
                  <Font size="24.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the same controller class for controllers from different FXML files? Don't do that - it's impossible to keep track of which fields are initialized in which controllers. At any rate, you need to set the text of the labels in the controller that is created when you load `FinalDay.fxml`, not the controller on which you call `displayTime()`.

Comment: So I should have the same amount of controllers as FXML files?

Comment: You should have the same number of controller *classes* as FXML files. You will (regardless of the number of controller classes) have one controller for every time you load an FXML file. (So if you have one FXML file, but load it twice, you will have two controllers.)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm finally getting the text to appear on my final window, much appreciated!